# Reading a file in java and placing its contents into a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, file

I am trying to read a file and place the contents into a 2D array starting from line 5. I do get the program to run without errors, but something goes wrong and it does not fill the array.

I tested around and found that something seems to go wrong after I introduce a while loop. The first 4 lines of the file are read successfully one by one outside the while loop, so the problem should not be with the filereader itself.

This is the while loop that should read the remaining lines and place each character of each string into a 2D array:

```
while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {
   String fileLine = fileReader.nextLine();

   int k = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < fileLine.length(); i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
         fileArray[k][j] = fileLine.charAt(i);
      }
   }
   k++
}
```

However, if I try to print the array, it simply prints empty lines. Why doesn't it fill the array and why doesn't it give any errors? And of course, how could I fix this code to make it work?

// Edit. Here is the entire code, as something more seems to be wrong with it than just the for loop (which I fixed for this):

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Filer {

   public static void main (String[] args) {
      Scanner fileReader = null;
      char[][] fileArray = null;

      try {
         String fileName = "alphabet.txt";
         File textFile = new File(fileName);
         fileReader = new Scanner(fileName);

         String line1 = fileReader.nextLine();
         int rows = Integer.parseInt(line1);

         String line2 = fileReader.nextLine();
         int columns = Integer.parseInt(line2);

         fileArray = new char[rows][columns];

         char line3 = fileReader.nextLine().charAt(0);
         char line4 = fileReader.nextLine().charAt(0);

         int i = 0;

         while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {
            String fileLine = fileReader.nextLine();
            for (int r = 0; r < fileLine.length(); r++) {
               fileArray[i][r] = fileLine.charAt(r);
            }
            i++;
         }

         fileReader.close();
      }

      catch (Exception e) {
         if (fileReader != null) {
            fileReader.close();
         }
      }

      if (fileArray != null) {
         for (int i = 0; i < fileArray.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(fileArray[i]);
            System.out.println();
         }
      }
      else {
         System.out.println("Error!");
      }
   }
}
```

The file contents are:

```
4
4
x
o
xxxx
xxox
ooxo
xxxx
```

Comment: You have two nested loops to read the characters of a single line. And in the loop, you always fill fileArray[k], where k is always 0. You need to rethink this loop completely. It's unclear what it's supposed to do, so it's hard to help.

Comment: share the sample data present from 5th line.

Comment: The k is supposed to represent the rows and I reasoned that it should work like that because doesn't it grow when the while loop restarts? So lets say that if the 5th line in the text file would be "abcdefg", the for loops would place the characters one by one into the array based on the index numbers (k for rows and j for columns), which would make the first row of the array be 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'. After that the k would increase by one so that the characters from the 6th line of the file would be placed on the second row in the array.

Comment: I edited the post and included the entire code in case there is something wrong with it somewhere else. This is my first time dealing with files in java so I'm sure it's a mess, but would really appreciate the help.

Comment: Perhaps someone more experienced sees the "real" problem here, but correct me if I'm wrong: Since you defined fileArray inside the try-section, it's not visible outside for if-loop to work with?

Comment: What is the content of you file? I ran localy and it displayed valid input

Comment: I just noticed the fileArray mistake myself. I think I messed up the code even more when translating it into English and deleting "unnecessary" parts to make it simpler. (The very original code includes two methods and a main, and bunch of other stuff that the teacher wants us to do just for the sake of doing it.)

I added the content of the file to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier, you had some syntax error but I can see that you have corrected them now. Given below is the working code. Run it and let me know if it works.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Filer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner fileReader = null;
        char[][] fileArray = null;

        try {
            File file = new File("alphabet.txt");
            if (file.exists()) {
                fileReader = new Scanner(file);
            } else {
                System.out.println("The file does not exist");
            }

            String line1 = fileReader.nextLine();
            int rows = Integer.parseInt(line1);

            String line2 = fileReader.nextLine();
            int columns = Integer.parseInt(line2);

            fileArray = new char[rows][columns];

            char line3 = fileReader.nextLine().charAt(0);
            char line4 = fileReader.nextLine().charAt(0);

            int i = 0;

            while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {
                String fileLine = fileReader.nextLine();
                for (int r = 0; r < fileLine.length(); r++) {
                    fileArray[i][r] = fileLine.charAt(r);
                }
                i++;
            }    
            fileReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if (fileReader != null) {
                fileReader.close();
            }
        }

        if (fileArray != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < fileArray.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(fileArray[i]);
                System.out.println();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it did work, thank you! However, it seems that after trying things out myself, I have found that the original problem I had was related to something I left out from the code I posted here. I didn't mention that I also need to place the characters from lines 3 & 4 into a completely different array (1D array). Apparently I do it wrong, which messes up the rest of the code that works when I leave this 1D array out. Anyway, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

How about like this?

```
int i = 0;
while (fileReader.hasNextLine()) {
      String fileLine = fileReader.nextLine();
      for (int r = 0; r < fileLine.length(); r++) {
          fileArray[i][r] = fileLine.charAt(r);
          }
      i++;
      }
```

You only need to loop through the line in the file (The for loop I have here). No other loop is necessary.

Comment: This loop makes more sense but somehow I still have the same problem: the array prints out empty. I also tried removing the for loop altogether (to break the code into pieces to find the problem) and just printing the fileLine string but it does not print it either.

Comment: Perhaps you need to post the whole code here for us to pin point the problem. It's hard to tell what's the case otherwise.